# Why does the_date work in the first custom column, but not in the second, in a series of customized Posts columns?

Tags: posts, admin

Interesting challenge. I was given a piece of code earlier, which I have modified as follows for the Posts page.

```
/* add time stamp */
add_filter('manage_posts_columns', 'posts_columns', 5);
function posts_columns($defaults){
    $defaults['your_date_col'] = __('Date');
    $defaults['week_number'] = __('Wk#');
    $defaults['week_in_quarter'] = __('Wk/Qtr');
    return $defaults;
}
add_action('manage_posts_custom_column', 'posts_custom_columns', 5, 2);
function posts_custom_columns($column_name, $id){
    if($column_name === 'your_date_col'){
    echo the_date('d M'),' ',the_time('Ha');
    }
    if($column_name === 'week_number'){
    echo 'Here: ',the_date();
    }
}
```

Strangely, although the date format that I have given shows up in the first column ("your_date_col"), only "Here: " shows up in the second column ("week_number"). Any suggestions as to why the_date function doesn't work in the second column?

Comment: I've found `the_date()` to always behave strangely, I believe there's a note about it in the codex. I use `get_the_date()` or `the_time()` instead.

Comment: I was *just* coming here to write that up. I realized that in the browse menu, for some reason some of the dates were only showing a time - because the date had already been shown on a previous post. Switching to get_the_date works. Thanks.

Comment: But I don't know how to mark this as answered.

Answer (score 1):

1) `the_date()` **echoes** the date value, so this statement isn't correct:

```
echo the_date('d M');
```

It should be:

```
the_date('d M');
```

2) If you have some posts posted on the same date, `the_date()` will **show only the date value for the 1st post**. There will be no result for remained posts.

To get date of all post, use `get_the_date()` (which returns date value) or `the_time()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

There is a explanation at top in [`the_date` function reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_date). I try to use always [the_time()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/the_time) instead.